# importing a js file that has import at it's top

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want to import a file that imports another file to be able to use it on multiple pages

folder structure

```
js
  modules
    momentum-scrolling
  index.js
  about.js
  contact.js
```

momentum-scrolling.js

```
import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';
export const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true
});
```

index.js

```
import './modules/momentum-scrolling'
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // some code
});
```

Comment: Mod note - I removed some comments because they were bordering on unprofessional. Konya, hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question was placed on-hold because folks are having a difficult time figuring out what you'd need in an answer, because it's not quite clear what you're asking. It may seem clear to you, but it's really hard to determine the actual problem. If you edit your question and include some more details, it can be re-opened and answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that in order for these imports to work correctly, you'll need to include type="module" in the html script tag.  Like this:

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```